# Saving an Excel file with filters and conditionals applied

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working with MS Excel and I need to save a file with a lot of filters and conditionals applied to many books. Is there any way to do it in each book? (I mean without copy-paste in new books).

In order to clarify: when I apply a filter data and save the file, the data is saved without filters applied. The same is true for conditionals. Only solution that I have found it is copy filtered data and paste in a new book.

Comment: I think have a "master" data spreadsheet, then in all of the other books have individual  power queries that filters the data you want. You may have to get into the settings and turn on refresh on open or something like that.

Comment: @MAL,,,, whatever filter has been applied on the current WB,,,, and if you are Saving it ,,, Execl doesn't removes the AUTO FILTER APPLIED,,,, I mean to say you still find the FILTER buttons aside of Column Headings,,,, APPLIED FILTERs are ONE TIME execution,,, XL doesn't keeps any FILTER METHOD on Automatic mode,,,,, U can do one thing,,, Apply Filter then Save the Filtered Data,, and next save the file WITHOUT Removing FILTERs,,,, but next either U have to Remove or Apply NEW Filter ,,,in case of Advance  Filter this happens also !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft 365 Apps, please try to save your workbooks on OneDrive or SharePoint.

Then you can go to View > Create a new view, apply filters and cinditionals for each book.

[image]